# PHP using recursive function to convert item to hex

Tags: php, recursion

I have a string and I would like to convert it to hex

```
$text = 'hello';
$hex = dec2hex($text);
```

Now I want to convert the string `$hex` again to hex and repeat it for 5 times. I could do this by using `$hex = dec2hex($hex)` for another 4 times.

I think a recursive function works better and is more efficient. This is what I tried but I didn't manage to get an output.

```
 $num = 5;
 $text = 'Hello';

function converter($n,$input) {

  if ( $n == 0 ) {
    return  $input;
  }


  $n = $n-1;
  $input = dec2hex($input);
  return $n;
  return $input;
}

echo "The code is: " . converter($num, $text);
```

I'm getting an output of 4. I want to get the hex of `hello` up to 5 levels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a recursive function, but you don't use recursion in your example.

A simple change to make it recursive:

```
function converter($n,$input) {

  if ( $n == 0 ) {
    return  $input;
  }


  $n = $n-1;
  $input = dec2hex($input);
  return converter($n, $input);
}
```

You forgot the recursive call.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
$num = 5;
$text = 'Hello';

function converter($n,$input) {

  if ( $n == 0 ) {
    return  $input;
  }


  $n = $n-1;
  $input = dec2hex($input);
  converter($input, $n); // I have changed this line.
}

echo "The code is: " . converter($num, $text);
```

I hope this will work.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like below:-

```
<?php
$input = 'hello';
$n  = 5;
function converter($n,$input) {
  $result = $input;
 for($i = 1;$i<=$n;$i++){
    $result = dec2hex($result);
  }

  return "iteration:".$n." and output is:-".$result;

}

echo converter($n,$input);
```

Note:- Since you are sending number of times you want the function `dec2hex()` to apply, so no need to recursively call function again and again just use loop.